# Error 0 couldn't connect to host in wamp windows 7

Tags: php, git, joomla, windows-7, wamp

I have a joomla GIT repository of my project. We are using wamp and windows 7 as a development environment. This repository works fine on one machine. But when we tried to clone same repository on other two machines, we are facing a strange error.

**Error is:** `Error 0 couldn't connect to host`

As shown in screenshot.[image]

All other repositories on those two machines work fine.

There is no error logged in under any of error logs file (apache, php and mysql).
I enabled joomla's error reporting. Searched on Google but, no luck.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked `http://localhost/` is working or not?

Comment: Yes, all other repositories work fine. Issue is only with this repo. And there is no error log in apache, php, mysql.

Comment: Can you confirm the configuration.php information in correct? Specifically the database connection details. Is the localhost working to serve up general .php files or is this just an issue connecting to Joomla?

Comment: I already confirmed configuration.php. It seems correct. I debugged index.php. Control goes till this line `$app->execute();` I didn't get your second question, please explain.

Comment: Are both environments are the same version of W7? Does PHPMyAdmin open?

Comment: Yes. Both versions are same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I debugged little bit more and finally found the solution. It was a small issue with missing web service link in one table. We are using com_api for web services. On first machine web service link value in table was local value respective to that machine.

On remaining two machines, we updated this to local value of those respective machines.

And it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

When you clone your Joomla to another machine, there are several things you need to double check:

- Not only the files from the GIT, make sure the database is the same on the other two machines as well (export from the first one, import to 2 other one using phpMyAdmin).
- Make sure the configuration.php file on two other machines re-corrected, includes: path to logs, tmp folders; database information (host, username, password, database name).

It should works.

Comment: I already did that. Infact, when I kept same copy of clone and database from my machine to first machine. It works.

Comment: No it's not. As I said it works on first machine but not on the other two.

Comment: which version of Joomla you are using? Are you sure your database has been imported ok on the other two?

Comment: I am using Joomla 3.1 and yes I am sure the database has been imported successfully.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a standard Joomla error - it's either that this error is thrown by an extension or it is a server error.

Try adding a die(); at the beginning of your index.php file and see if it actually dies, if it doesn't, then this is definitely a server error.

If it does die, the use the function: get_included_files() and then make a quick search on all the files included on that page for the sentence "Couldn't connect". You will find the culprit easily this way.

Comment: Sorry. I was bit busy with some other work. I tried adding `die();` at the beginning of index.php file, yes it does die. Now I am not getting where should I use the function `get_included_files()`? I even debugged index.php using die(); control goes till this line `$app->execute();`

Answer (score 0):

Check your .htaccess file, maybe they have some rule which can not be met. (Rename this file if it exists and see what happening)
But I think that the problem is in the network settings. Errors often come from dns issues or, curl connection restrictions.

- Check your DNS records
- Check your Curl settings and try to create any Curl request.
- Check your .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this error related to Joomla , I think it is connection from PHP to Linux, try to change the port of the Linux.

and restart the Apache and try again.